# How to use favicon with the asset pipeline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I'm implementing a favicon using an online generator (http://realfavicongenerator.net but other generators such as www.favicon-generator.org work the same). The generator supplies almost 30 files (images for android, apple, different sizes, etc.), which is why I placed all these files in the asset pipeline (`assets/images/favicons/`) instead of in the public folder (which would otherwise get so cluttered).

Included in the files are an xml file `browserconfig.xml` and a json file `manifest.json` (not sure what they are for exactly). In the header I load both files using:

```
<%= content_tag :meta, nil, content: image_path("favicons/browserconfig.xml"), name: 'msapplication-config' %>
<%= content_tag :link, nil, href: image_path("favicons/manifest.json"), rel: :manifest %>
```

**Is it okay to use `image_path` this way?** (even though they are not images, I have placed all favicon files together in one folder inside `assets/images/favicons`)

Further, both the xml and json file contain references to favicon images (see below) that are now in the asset pipeline. So in its current form, these references fail. **How can I refer to the images in the xml and json files?**

browserconfig.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<browserconfig>
  <msapplication>
    <tile>
      <square70x70logo src="/mstile-70x70.png"/>
      <square150x150logo src="/mstile-150x150.png"/>
      <square310x310logo src="/mstile-310x310.png"/>
      <wide310x150logo src="/mstile-310x150.png"/>
      <TileColor>#fff8dc</TileColor>
    </tile>
  </msapplication>
</browserconfig>
```

manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "AppName",
  "icons": [
    {
        "src": "\/android-chrome-36x36.png",
        "sizes": "36x36",
        "type": "image\/png",
        "density": "0.75"
    },
    {
        "src": "\/android-chrome-48x48.png",
        "sizes": "48x48",
        "type": "image\/png",
        "density": "1.0"
    },
    # etc.
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is better to place the favicon in your public folder, because otherwise it will contain a fingerprint in the name, when it will be compiled

Answer (score 3):

It proved less difficult then expected. I renamed the two files to `.xml.erb` and `.json.erb` and recoded the references using Ruby/Rails `image_path`. Now I think the references work.